# Set a whole column in `QTableWidget` read-only in python

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyside

i want to set a column in my table to read-only! i tried all possible combinations of flags without success

```
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    from operator import xor
    item.setFlags(xor(item.flags(),QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable))
    self.Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
```

i also tried `and not`, `!=` and `^` operators but the column items are still editable

---

## Update

I think i was misunderstanding this! i thought when i set the HorizontalHeaderItem at a column to be not editable, that will make all new items in that column to be automatically not editable, when using the operations like `insertRow()`

I had perform these function to each new added item after inserting new row!

```
        tableWidget.insertRow(row+1)
        if  tableWidget is self.myTable:
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setFlags(item.flags() != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 4, item)
```

I think a better (but more complex) solution is to use `setItemDelegateForColumn()` and `QtGui.QItemDelegate()` to create a read-only costum `QTableWidgetItem` which will be added each time a new row is inserted or created

---

## Edit

Well i tried to use `setItemDelegateForColumn()` and `QtGui.QItemDelegate()` as mentioned above but i got the following Warning

```
> python main.py
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: Invalid return value in function QItemDelegate.createEdit
or, expected PySide.QtGui.QWidget, got PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.
```

My code for that was

```
class QTableWidgetDisabledItem(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):

        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setFlags(item.flags() != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        return item

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.blockSignals(True)
        editor.setData(index, editor.text())
        editor.blockSignals(False)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())
```

and in the MainWindow

```
    self.Size = QTableWidgetDisabledItem(self.MyTable)
    self.MyTable.setItemDelegateForColumn(4,self.Size)
```

It was good idea though ...

Comment: Did you try to remove `Qt.ItemIsEnabled` flag from all items of the column?

Comment: @vahancho you mean with a loop ?

Comment: Yes, in the loop, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working using `QLineEditor`

```
class QTableWidgetDisabledItem(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    """
    Create a readOnly QTableWidgetItem
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):

        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        item = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        item.setReadOnly(True)
        #item.setEnabled(False)
        return item

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.blockSignals(True)
        editor.setText(index.model().data(index))
        editor.blockSignals(False)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())
```

and then just simply use it as follow

```
self.Size = QTableWidgetDisabledItem(self.MyTable)
self.MyTable.setItemDelegateForColumn(4,self.Size)
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
    flags != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
    item.setFlags(flags)
```

this worked for me last time :-)

EDIT: sorry for not being more detailed here. Of course you need to apply to every item in desired column, example:

```
flags = Qt.ItemFlags()
flags != Qt.ItemIsEnabled

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        item = QTableWidgetItem('Row %s Column %s' % (r,c))
        if c == 2:
            item.setFlags(flags)
        table.setItem(r, c, item)
```

Will set column 3 to read-only items in that column. HTH

Comment: you mean `flags = item.flags() != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable` ? i tried it but didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

The solution shown above can be simplified to:

```
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, *args):
        return None

table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(2, 2)
table.setItemDelegateForColumn(MyDelegate())
```

This solution differs from the `ItemIsEditable` solution in the sense that you can still select and highlight items in the column.